# Redirecting subdomain 301 instead of 302

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a 302 redirect from

> `http://www.subdomain.mydomain.com` and `http://subdomain.mydomain.com` to
>   `https://www.subdomain.mydomain.com` and then a 301 redirect to
>   `https://subdomain.mydomain.com`

That is one step too much. Tried everything in the .htacces

How do I solve the redirects with one step?:

`http://www.subdomain.mydomain.com` and `http://subdomain.mydomain.com` with a 301 to `https://subdomain.mydomain.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain\.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://subdomain.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```